# Google cloud Create image from instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a VM which is up and running and I have few applications in the VM. So I want to have an image of this VM so that I can create new instances with all the installed packages. I have option called clone, but instead cloning a VM I wanted to have it as an Image and create VM whenever I want.

Answer (score 12):

It's described here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image

Basically what it boils down to:

1. Set the auto-delete state of the root persistent disk to false so that it is not automatically deleted when you delete the instance.
2. Delete the instance.
3. `gcloud compute images create example-image --source-disk example-disk --source-disk-zone ZONE`

Comment: Do we have to delete instances  to create image?

Comment: Not anymore. A lot has improved in 4 years. See the docs for updated instructions.

Comment: Yes, I did it and we don't have to delete the  instance which sounds not a good idea as well.

Answer (score -2):

```
https://github.com/khushbuparakh/gcp/blob/master/instance.py
```

You can use this. It creates a bucket. Upload your private file to the bucket. Create an image using that file and spin up an instance. Make sure the file you are uploading to bucket is in tar.gz compressed format with a disk.raw file in it.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more about this? I don't see my own instance create-image option or save to file option.