# how to take an Image on running VM in Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to find a way to take the image of a running instance.
I can't see any option take an image as we have in AWS.

I have seen the create image option but it creates but it needs the source disk, I have created the instance and can't see the existing disk.

Does anyone have any Idea, if Google Cloud provide this feature or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google cloud Create image from instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701516/google-cloud-create-image-from-instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a snapshot of the virtual machine. See this link: https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/snapshots?project=your-project-id. You have to click on "Create Snapshot"